# Querying indirectly associated entities in HQL

Tags: join, hql, nhibernate-hql

**NB: I am using NHibernate 2.1 (for legacy code support)**

If I have three entities:

1. **A** related to **B**
2. **C** related to **B**

That is, having the following properties:

**Entity A**

> ```
> A
> - id
> - B
> ```

**Entity B**

> ```
> B
> - id
> ```

**Entity C**

> ```
> C
> - id
> - B
> ```

How do I do it using a non-theta-style join?

If I try something like this

```
from A a
inner join a.B b
inner join C.b cB
where
a.B_id = b.id and
cB.id = b.id
```

I get the exception: `Path expected for join!`

Is a theta join the only way I can get it to work or am I missing something?

If I have no direct association from A to C why can I not associate through another entity? Or does this not work?

Comment: You don't have any b.C, so your query can't work. You also don't have any C_id in B, not any B_id in A BTW.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, corrected my example.

Comment: You're still trying to do `inner join b.C`, although there is no C field in B. How could that possibly work?

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks. corrected